# Why do I get occasional timeout errors when retrieving specific images with Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

This problem happens rarely, i.e. only with specific images. How should I avoid it?

this does work:

```
response = requests.get(url='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XFloD6F3Tws/VPW9r8e3fzI/AAAAAAAH77c/izzZRWSbGdk/s1600/16467_1197957903548615_3921728777903612927_n.jpg', stream=True, timeout=60)
response.text
```

but this does not:

```
response = requests.get(url='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6SnMAxnWLKM/VPTIf5AMcDI/AAAAAAAH7zA/wNRxXAcH_e4/s1600/Ανώνυμο-1.jpg', stream=True, timeout=60)
response.text
```

in fact, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 186, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 500, in read
    return super(HTTPResponse, self).read(amt)
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 539, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 371, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 638, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 256, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 201, in read
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='1.bp.blogspot.com', port=80): Read timed out.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 734, in text
    if not self.content:
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 707, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 645, in generate
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='1.bp.blogspot.com', port=80): Read timed out.
```

**EDIT**

This is the error I get when I apply `.encode("utf-8")` on the url string.

```
>>> response = requests.get(url='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6SnMAxnWLKM/VPTIf5AMcDI/AAAAAAAH7zA/wNRxXAcH_e4/s1600/Ανώνυμο-1.jpg'.encode("utf-8"), stream=True, timeout=60)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 48, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 451, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 551, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/home/eualin/.bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'b'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6SnMAxnWLKM/VPTIf5AMcDI/AAAAAAAH7zA/wNRxXAcH_e4/s1600/\xce\x91\xce\xbd\xcf\x8e\xce\xbd\xcf\x85\xce\xbc\xce\xbf-1.jpg''
>>>
```

Comment: Perhaps, one image was encoded such that you could retrieve one but not the other.

Comment: I don't understand... How can I see both on the web browser but unable to retrieve both?

Comment: If you look in the second url, you'll see that there are Unicode characters.

Comment: my browser shows these characters too. there must be something else. what else can happen here?

Comment: `.encode("utf-8")` throws exception. `response.content` doesn't make any difference; I still get the time out.

Comment: I think, my problem doesn't not get any simpler than that: I have two image urls that can be accessed via browser. However, for some strange reasons, the second one cannot be retrieve via python whereas the first one does. I just want to fetch the image from the web and print the results in the terminal. That's all! So, any ideas?

Comment: I always quote with single quotes. I have never used both types of quotes at the same time as you say... not sure were you saw that...

Comment: That is the only way I can replicate your error.  The url looks fine when encoded.  what version of requests are you using?

Comment: according to this `http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs.html`, I use `2.4.1`

Comment: I would update, the latest is 2.5.3

Comment: I did that too but no chance...

Comment: when you print the url what does it look like?